# How can I save Calendar Information in real time database?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have implemented a calendar widget in my app and can display event details in app. However, whenever I close and open the application again, the appointment details are not saved. I would like to save the details in real-time firebase and have the ability of retaining the information after I close the app. Below is the code snippet. Any assistance will help out:

```
class EventEditingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Event? event;
  const EventEditingPage({
    Key? key,
    this.event,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<EventEditingPage> createState() => _EventEditingPageState();
}

class _EventEditingPageState extends State<EventEditingPage> {
  final fb = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
  final databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('Appointments');
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final titleController = TextEditingController();
  late DateTime fromDate;
  late DateTime toDate;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.event == null) {
      fromDate = DateTime.now();
      toDate = DateTime.now().add(const Duration(hours: 2));
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    titleController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //  final databaseRef = fb.ref().child('Appointments');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: const CloseButton(),
        actions: buildEditingActions(),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
            buildTitle(),
            const SizedBox(height: 15),
            buildDatePickers(),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> buildEditingActions() => [
        ElevatedButton.icon(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(shadowColor: Colors.transparent),
            onPressed: saveForm,
              

            icon: const Icon(Icons.done),
            label: const Text('Save'))
      ];

  Widget buildTitle() => TextFormField(
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
          hintText: 'Add Title',
        ),
        validator: (title) =>
            title != null && title.isEmpty ? 'Title cannot be Empty' : null,
        onFieldSubmitted: (_) => saveForm(),
        controller: titleController,
      );

  Widget buildDatePickers() => Column(
        children: [
          buildFrom(),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          buildTo(),
        ],
      );
  Widget buildFrom() => buildHeader(
        header: 'From',
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: buildDropdownField(
                text: Utils.toDate(fromDate),
                onClicked: () => pickFromDateTime(pickDate: true),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: buildDropdownField(
                text: Utils.toTime(fromDate),
                onClicked: () => pickFromDateTime(pickDate: false),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
  Widget buildDropdownField({
    required String text,
    required VoidCallback onClicked,
  }) =>
      ListTile(
        title: Text(text),
        trailing: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
        onTap: onClicked,
      );

  Widget buildHeader({required String header, required Widget child}) => Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            header,
            style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          child,
        ],
      );
  Future saveForm() async {
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState!.validate();
    if (isValid) {
      final event = Event(
        eventName: titleController.text,
        from: fromDate,
        to: toDate,
        isAllDay: false,
        description: 'Description',

      );


      final provider = Provider.of<EventProvider>(context, listen: false);
      provider.addEvent(event);
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    }
  }

  Widget buildTo() => buildHeader(
        header: 'To',
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: buildDropdownField(
                text: Utils.toDate(toDate),
                onClicked: () => pickToDateTime(pickDate: true),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: buildDropdownField(
                text: Utils.toTime(toDate),
                onClicked: () => pickToDateTime(pickDate: false),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
  Future pickFromDateTime({required bool pickDate}) async {
    final date = await pickDateTime(fromDate, pickDate: pickDate);
    if (date == null) return;
    if (date.isAfter(toDate)) {
      toDate =
          DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day, toDate.hour, toDate.minute);
    }
    setState(() => fromDate = date);
  }

  Future pickToDateTime({required bool pickDate}) async {
    final date = await pickDateTime(
      toDate,
      pickDate: pickDate,
      firstDate: pickDate ? fromDate : null,
    );
    if (date == null) return;
    if (date.isAfter(toDate)) {
      toDate =
          DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day, toDate.hour, toDate.minute);
    }
    setState(() => toDate = date);
  }

  Future<DateTime?> pickDateTime(
    DateTime initialDate, {
    required bool pickDate,
    DateTime? firstDate,
  }) async {
    if (pickDate) {
      final date = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: initialDate,
        firstDate: firstDate ?? DateTime(2022, 9),
        lastDate: DateTime(2200),
      );
      if (date == null) return null;
      final time =
          Duration(hours: initialDate.hour, minutes: initialDate.minute);
      return date.add(time);
    } else {
      final timeOfDay = await showTimePicker(
        context: context,
        initialTime: TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(initialDate),
      );
      if (timeOfDay == null) return null;
      final date = DateTime(
        initialDate.year,
        initialDate.month,
        initialDate.day,
      );
      final time = Duration(hours: timeOfDay.hour, minutes: timeOfDay.minute);
      return date.add(time);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The use-case is clear, but Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger. When you set breakpoints on each line of the code you shared, run in the debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line of the code that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Let me work on that. I'll give you feedback